# Conversion of implicit to explicit function

Tags: calculus

Is there any way to express 
$$e^{-rp}=1-pq$$
($p, q, r$ are reals satisfying the expression) as  "$p$ in terms of $q,r$"?

Comment: I don't think you may find an explicit form for the implicit function. But what is the purpose? To be able to find numerical values? Or some theoretical property of an implicit function? Because then there are ways to proceed

Comment: I came across this situation in solving another problem. But if it has no explicit form, then I need to deviate from this situation. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Btw. the implicit function will be singluar for $q-re^{-rp}=0$ (the IFT fails). And you may also reduce to just one parameter by replacing e.g. $pq$ by $p$.

Comment: That is right. Thanks for your  analysis.